# Sencha find Row in Object

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I have a object list. This object filling by json data. Example Json data:

```
{"id":2677,"name":"------------------","stockCode":"RM0001","groupId":200000,"price":0.0,"color":"LightCyan","type":3,"mustModGrpCount":0,"mustModGroups":"","order":0,"campCount":0,"populer":false},{"id":398,"name":"KUVER","stockCode":"URN0380","groupId":200021,"price":0.0,"color":"aliceblue","type":3,"mustModGrpCount":0,"mustModGroups":"","order":0,"campCount":0,"populer":false}
```

**I need to access ------------------ element.**

Tried this but doesnt work.

```
var b=NewMobile.globals.products.getByField('name','------------------');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed :

```
var key =NewMobile.globals.products.findExact("stockCode","RM0001");
        var prd = NewMobile.globals.products.getAt(key);
```

Comment: Fixed *how*? You should explain it more :)

Comment: variable.findExact("stockCode","RM0001"); is returns index value if  "stockCode" field equal "RM0001" value.

and getting the row in object with NewMobile.globals.products.getAt(key);